# Download multiple GCS files in parallel (into memory) using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a storage bucket with a lot of large files (500mb each). At times I need to load multiple files, referenced by name.  I have been using the `blob.download_as_string()` function to download the files one-by-one, but it's extremely slow so I would like to try and download them in parallel instead.

I found the `gcloud-aio-storage` package, however the documentation is a bit sparse, especially for the `download` function.

I would prefer to download / store the files in memory instead of downloading to local machine then upload to script.

This is what I've pieced together, though I can't seem to get this to work. I keep getting a timeout error.   **What am I doing wrong?**

Note: Using python 3.7, and latest of all other packages.

*test_download.py*

```
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage
import aiohttp 
import asyncio

async def gcs_download(session, bucket_name, file, storage):
    async with session: 
        bucket = storage.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = await bucket.get_blob(file)
        return  await blob.download()
    

async def get_gcsfiles_async(bucket_name, gcs_files):

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        storage = Storage(session=session)
        coros = (gcs_download(session, bucket_name, file, storage) for file in gcs_files)
        return await asyncio.gather(*coros)
```

Then the way I'm calling / passing in values are as follows:

```
import test_download as test
import asyncio

bucket_name = 'my_bucket_name'
project_name = 'my_project_name'  ### Where do I reference this???

gcs_files = ['bucket_folder/some-file-2020-10-06.txt', 
            'bucket_folder/some-file-2020-10-07.txt',
            'bucket_folder/some-file-2020-10-08.txt']

result = asyncio.run(test.get_gcsfiles_async(bucket_name, gcs_files))
```

**Any help would be appreciated!**

Here is related question, although there are two things to note: [Google Storage python api download in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508478/google-storage-python-api-download-in-parallel/51522939)

1. When I run the code from the approved answer it ends up getting stuck and never downloads
2. It's from before the `gcloud-aio-storage` package was released and might not be leveraging the "best" current methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation for that library is lacking, but I could get something running, and it is working on my tests. Something I found out by looking at the code is that you don’t need to use `blob.download()`, since [it calls](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/blob/master/storage/gcloud/aio/storage/blob.py#L77) `storage.download()` anyways. I based the script below on the [usage](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/tree/master/storage#usage) section, which deals with uploads, but can be rewritten for downloading. `storage.download()` does not write to a file, since that is done by `storage.download_to_filename()`. You can check the available download methods [here](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/blob/master/storage/gcloud/aio/storage/storage.py#L240-L294).

**async_download.py**

```python
import asyncio
from gcloud.aio.auth import Token
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage

# Used a token from a service account for authentication
sa_token = Token(service_file="../resources/gcs-test-service-account.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"])

async def async_download(bucket, obj_names):
    async with Storage(token=sa_token) as client:
        tasks = (client.download(bucket, file) for file in obj_names) # Used the built in download method, with required args
        res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    await sa_token.close()
    return res
```

**main.py**

```python
import async_download as dl_test
import asyncio

bucket_name = "my-bucket-name"
obj_names = [
    "text1.txt",
    "text2.txt",
    "text3.txt"
]

res = asyncio.run(dl_test.async_download(bucket_name, obj_names))

print(res)
```

If you want to use a Service Account `Token` instead, you can follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) and use the relevant [auth scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#storage). Since Service Accounts are project-wise, specifying a project is not needed, but I did not see any project name references for a `Session` either. While the GCP Python library for GCS does not yet support parallel downloads, there is a [feature request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/111828021) open for this. There is no ETA for a release of this yet.

Comment: Thanks Ernesto!  I'll try this out in a little bit.  Thanks for the code for a service account, that would be used when this is deployed.

Comment: I'm still getting a `concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError`.  I can't use a service on my local machine to test this, so that could be why.  But I also need to access the files in a folder within the bucket. So ```obj_names = [folder/text1.txt, folder/text2.txt]```, and not sure if that is an issue either.

Comment: @mrp I can confirm that having objects inside folders and referencing them as `folder/file.txt` still works on my testing. Your problem could be from not using a service account, since the [example](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/blob/master/storage/tests/integration/smoke_test.py#L29) uses a service account. You can also simplify your code and allow the library to automatically [manage](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/issues/396#issuecomment-963517591) the `session`. I added a missing `Token.close()` statement to the code. Let me know if this was helpful to refer to future users.

Comment: FWIW the download call will return a list of bytestrings, one entry for each file.  I made a blog post: https://layer77.net/2022/07/17/making-async-calls-to-google-cloud-storage/

Comment: if i wanted to return a tuple of filename and it's value how do i do that ?